# Can I remove the middle slave in a MySQL "master -> slave -> slave" setup?

Tags: mysql, replication

Let's say I have the following setup:

`Master` -> `Slave1` -> `Slave2`

I would like to remove the middle slave, `Slave1`, and have the following:

`Master` -> `Slave2`

My gut is that I can do the following:

1. Stop the `Master` -> `Slave1` replication.
2. After `Slave1` ->
   `Slave2` replication catches up, stop that replication as well.
3. `CHANGE MASTER` on `Slave2` to point to `Master`
4. Turn on replication on `Slave2`
5. Enjoy new `Master` -> `Slave2` setup.

Is this something that would work?

Answer (score 0):

Add additonal step to avoid any confusion you could do **flush tables with read lock** after replication is caught up as it will do global lock and would avoid conflict in case of any change coming up, use **unlock tables** at the end to release the lock acquired. Moreover it would be better to have this done in low/off production time in case it is in production, other steps seems to fine

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is some steps missing, depending on your needs. I am assuming you are using traditional, non-GTID replication.

1. Before doing any topology change, make sure that your slaves have the exact same dataset than the master. The current setup, with 2 jumps is double the change of having suffered some replication woe and having drift. I wouldn't go into details, but a tools like [pt-table-checksum](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-table-checksum.html) and [pt-table-sync](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-table-sync.html) can be very handy for this.
2. Your second step is nice, but if you blindly execute the `CHANGE MASTER`, by only changing the `MASTER_HOST`, you will end up with a broken replication because the binary log coordinates for master and slave1 are probably different. If you take the latest binary coordinates from the master, with `SHOW MASTER STATUS` you have a high chance of missing transactions because some may be executed on the master between the replication stop of M->S1 and the syncronization of S1->S2.

   So, what is the right way to do it? @NawazSohail suggests executing `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` on the master, but that will impact the availability of your system. A better way would be to execute `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` after step 2 on the slave1 and use its master coordinates in order to start slave2 in the right position. A similar solution is use the `START SLAVE UNTIL` on slave 1. If you want a more automated way, tools like [MHA](https://code.google.com/p/mysql-master-ha/) automatize the failover/switchover process.

   As working with files and coordinates is not the best way, since MySQL 5.6 we have GTIDs, which basically make the process much more transparent and easy. Executing a

   ```
   CHANGE MASTER MASTER_HOST='master-host' MASTER_AUTO_POSITION=1;
   ```

   Would be enough to execute the switchover. We also have tools like [mysqlfailover](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/en/mysqlfailover.html).
3. After step 5, you can run again pt-table-checksum to validate, if you want, the new setup.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but let me refine it

**STEP 01**: On Slave1, run `STOP SLAVE;`

**STEP 02**: On Slave1, run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` until `Seconds_Behind_Master` is 0

**STEP 03**: On Slave1, write down Relay_Master_Log_File (RMLF) and Exec_Master_Log_Pos (EMLP) from STEP 02

**STEP 04**: On Slave2, run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` until `Seconds_Behind_Master` is 0

**STEP 05**: On Slave2, run this

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO
    master_host='IP of Master',
    master_port=3306,
    master_user='...',
    master_password='...',
    master_log_file='<RMLF from STEP 03>',
    master_log_pos='<EMLP from STEP 03>',
;
START SLAVE;
```

**STEP 06**: On Slave2, run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` until `Seconds_Behind_Master` is 0